# Espresso Test freezes when Use Host GPU is enabled

Tags: android, android-emulator, gpu, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a series of Espresso tests that test a slide menu. The majority of the tests fail when Use Host GPU is turned on, but not when it is disabled. Even though I have disabled animations, I think I might be missing a setting somewhere because I can still see the window sliding open. I am testing Android 4.4.2 and using HAXM. Why does this test fail?

Here's one example of a test (they all have the same structure):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void testClickOnItemDisplaysMyFragment() {
    openDrawer(DRAWER);
    onView(withId(DRAWER)).check(matches(isOpen()));
    onView(allOf(withId(DRAWER_ITEM), withText(MY_ITEM))).perform(click());
    onView(withId(DRAWER)).check(matches(isClosed()));

    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(FRAGMENT_LAYOUT);
    assertThat(fragment, is(notNullValue()));
    assertThat(fragment, is(instanceOf(MyFragment.class)));
    onView(withId(fragment.getId())).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

If I start my emulator without Use Host GPU checked, the tests pass fine. If Use Host GPU is enabled, the first test or so pass and then the rest fail with:

```
com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.IdlingResourceTimeoutException: Wait for [IdlingDrawerListener] to become idle timed out
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:579)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:69)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:40)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:159)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:133)
at com.example.MainActivityTest.testClickOnItemDisplaysMyFragment(MainActivityTest.java:152)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:167)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
```

I have tried disabling animations in the emulator, as described here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso#Getting_Started , but I can still see the drawer sliding open and closed.

Comment: this is happening to me too, but only on Windows machine - on OSX it works fine with GPU acceleration

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This                                             is a known bug: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=64